# Logical OR on a subset of columns in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I want to get all rows where (at least) one of the columns in df[mylist] contains True.

I'm currently doing:

```
df = df[ df[mylist[0]] | df[mylist[1]] | df[mylist[2]] ]
```

where `mylist` is a list of strings relating to columns of `df`. But I would like to do this for any length of `mylist`.

The only way I can think of to do this is to loop over `mylist` and create an new dataframe for each element of it and merge/concat or whatever them afterwards. But that doesn't look very smart for me.

Is there a better way?

Comment: sorry are you saying that `mylist` is a string of col names like `['col1', 'col2', col3']`? If so why don't you just do `df[myList]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building on LondonRob's answer, you could use

```
df.loc[df[mylist].any(axis=1)]
```

Calling the DataFrame's `any` method will perform better than using `apply` to call Python's builtin `any` function once per row.

Or you could use [`np.logical_or.reduce`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduce.html):

```
df.loc[np.logical_or.reduce(df[mylist], axis=1)]
```

For large DataFrames, using `np.logical_or` may be quicker:

```
In [30]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.binomial(1, 0.1, size=(100,300)).astype(bool))

In [31]: %timeit df.loc[np.logical_or.reduce(df, axis=1)]
1000 loops, best of 3: 261 µs per loop

In [32]: %timeit df.loc[df.any(axis=1)]
1000 loops, best of 3: 636 µs per loop

In [33]: %timeit df[df.apply(any, axis=1)]
100 loops, best of 3: 2.13 ms per loop
```

Note that `df.any` has extra features, such as the ability to skip NaNs. 
In this case, if the columns are boolean-valued, then there can not be any NaNs
(since NaNs are float values). So `np.logical_or.reduce` is quicker.

---

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(2014)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.binomial(1, 0.1, size=(10,3)).astype(bool), 
                  columns=list('ABC'))
print(df)
#        A      B      C
# 0  False  False  False
# 1   True  False  False
# 2  False  False  False
# 3   True  False  False
# 4  False  False  False
# 5  False  False  False
# 6  False   True  False
# 7  False  False  False
# 8  False  False  False
# 9  False  False  False

mylist = list('ABC')
print(df[ df[mylist[0]] | df[mylist[1]] | df[mylist[2]] ])
print(df.loc[df[mylist].any(axis=1)])
print(df.loc[np.logical_or.reduce(df[mylist], axis=1)])
```

yields the rows where at least one of the columns is True:

```
       A      B      C
1   True  False  False
3   True  False  False
6  False   True  False
```

Answer (score 4):

There's a *much* simpler way to do this using python's built in [`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) function:

```
In []: mylist
Out[]: ['A', 'B']

In []: df
Out[]: 
       A      B      C
0  False  False  False
1   True  False  False
2  False  False  False
3   True  False  False
4  False  False  False
5  False  False  False
6  False   True  False
7  False  False  False
8  False  False  False
9  False  False  False
```

You can [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) the function `any` along the rows of `df` by using `axis=1`. In this case I'll only apply `any` to a subset of the columns:

```
In []: df[mylist].apply(any, axis=1)
Out[]: 
0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
4    False
5    False
6     True
7    False
8    False
9    False
dtype: bool
```

This gives us the perfect way to select our rows:

```
In []: df[df[mylist].apply(any, axis=1)]
Out[]: 
       A      B      C
1   True  False  False
3   True  False  False
6  False   True  False
```

Comment: After re-reading the now clearer question I realise my answer had nothing to do with what the OP had wanted albeit the OP had worded their question in a highly obfuscated way