# How to copy/paste DataFrame from Stack Overflow into Python

Tags: python, pandas, clipboard

In [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17729853/2071807) and [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31609618/2071807), users very often post an example `DataFrame` which their question/answer works with:

```
In []: x
Out[]: 
   bar  foo
0    4    1
1    5    2
2    6    3
```

It'd be really useful to be able to get this `DataFrame` into my Python interpreter so I can start debugging the question, or testing the answer.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Pandas is written by people that really know what people want to do.

[Since version `0.13`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#id45) there's a function [`pd.read_clipboard`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_clipboard.html) which is absurdly effective at making this "just work".

Copy and paste the part of the code in the question that starts `bar foo`, (i.e. the DataFrame) and do this in a Python interpreter:

```
In [53]: import pandas as pd
In [54]: df = pd.read_clipboard()

In [55]: df
Out[55]: 
   bar  foo
0    4    1
1    5    2
2    6    3
```

## Caveats

- Don't include the iPython `In` or `Out` stuff or it won't work
- If you have a named index, you currently need to add `engine='python'` (see [this issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/6893) on GitHub). The 'c' engine is currently broken when the index is named.
- It's not brilliant at MultiIndexes:

Try this:

```
                      0         1         2
level1 level2                              
foo    a       0.518444  0.239354  0.364764
       b       0.377863  0.912586  0.760612
bar    a       0.086825  0.118280  0.592211
```

which doesn't work at all, or this:

```
              0         1         2
foo a  0.859630  0.399901  0.052504
    b  0.231838  0.863228  0.017451
bar a  0.422231  0.307960  0.801993
```

Which works, but returns something totally incorrect!

Comment: Note that the dtype will be `object` i.e. `str` so you may need to do `df = df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)`

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the case with this particular example (the one in the OP). It's a good one to watch out for though.

Comment: Hmm, I've definitely observed that before but you're correct this does work correctly

Comment: I am wondering how you can copy and paste the input and output number in your code like you are showing here with `In [55]` and `Out[55]`. I'm using Jupyter Notebook and can't seem to find a way to do that.

Answer (score 20):

`pd.read_clipboard()` is nifty. However, if you're writing code in a script or a notebook (and you want your code to work in the future) it's not a great fit. Here's an alternative way to copy/paste the output of a dataframe into a new dataframe object that ensures that `df` will outlive the contents of your clipboard:

```
# py3 only, see below for py2
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

d = '''0   1   2   3   4
A   Y   N   N   Y
B   N   Y   N   N
C   N   N   N   N
D   Y   Y   N   Y
E   N   Y   Y   Y
F   Y   Y   N   Y
G   Y   N   N   Y'''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(d), sep='\s+')
```

A few notes:

- The triple-quoted string preserves the newlines in the output.
- `StringIO` wraps the output in a file-like object, which `read_csv` requires.
- Setting `sep` to `\s+` makes it so that each contiguous block of whitespace is treated as a single delimiter.

#### update

The above answer is Python 3 only. If you're stuck in Python 2, replace the import line:

```
from io import StringIO
```

with instead:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
```

If you have an old version of `pandas` (`v0.24` or older) there's an easy way to write a Py2/Py3 compatible version of the above code:

```
import pandas as pd

d = ...
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(d), sep='\s+')
```

The newest versions of `pandas` have dropped the `compat` module along with Python 2 support.

Comment: and better is use `pd.compat.StringIO`, then is no necessary `from io import StringIO`

Comment: In Python 3 it makes absolutely no difference (`pd.compat.StringIO is io.StringIO` is `True`), and is just a matter of style (import statement vs longer argument). However, I just checked, and it turns out that using `io.StringIO` in Python 2 leads to a nasty `bytes` vs `unicode` issue. I'd say that's definitely a good enough reason to prefer one over the other, so I'll change my answer to use `pd.compat.StringIO`.

Comment: You are missing import: according to your Python version, i.e. `from StringIO import StringIO` for Python 2 and `from io import StringIO` for Python 3 as stated in https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html.
With pandas 0.25.0 import will fail because of the https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/issues/655. Solution is to rollback to previous pandas version with: `pip3 install --upgrade pandas==0.24.2`

Comment: @Harvey Apparently, `pandas >= 0.25.0` has dropped the `compat` module, along with Python 2 support. I've updated my answer to reflect this

Answer (score 1):

If you are copy-pasting from CSV file which has standard entries like this:

```
2016,10,M,0600,0610,13,1020,24
2016,3,F,0300,0330,21,6312,1
2015,4,M,0800,0830,8,7112,30
2015,10,M,0800,0810,19,0125,1
2016,8,M,1500,1510,21,0910,2
2015,10,F,0800,0810,3,8413,5

df =pd.read_clipboard(sep=",", header=None)
df.rename(columns={0: "Name0", 1: "Name1",2:"Name2",3:"Name3",4:"Name4",5:"Name5",6:"Name6",7:"Name7",8:"Name8"})
```

will give you properly defined pandas Dataframe.

[image]