# How can I copy DataFrames with datetimes from Stack Overflow into Python?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, clipboard, copy-paste

I see frequent `pandas` examples on SO using time series that have *spaces within the timestamps*:

```
                     A
2020-01-01 09:20:00  0
2020-01-01 09:21:00  1
2020-01-01 09:22:00  2
2020-01-01 09:23:00  3
2020-01-01 09:24:00  4
```

Or this where the times aren't part of the index:

```
                dates    values cat
0 2020-01-01 09:20:00  0.758513   a
1 2020-01-01 09:21:00  0.337325   b
2 2020-01-01 09:22:00  0.618372   b
3 2020-01-01 09:23:00  0.878714   b
4 2020-01-01 09:24:00  0.311069   b
```

**Is there a good way to copy these (or similar) data back into Python to work with?**  I have found posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31610889/how-to-copy-paste-dataframe-from-stack-overflow-into-python) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) which were lifesavers for getting many examples out of SO, yet I usually fail to find a copy/paste approach (using `pd.read_clipboard()` or `pd.read_table()`) that works for such data.  This often then discourages me from attempting an answer<sup>1</sup>.

The examples above were created this way:

```
#one
import pandas as pd
import numpy

dr = pd.date_range('01-01-2020 9:20', '01-01-2020 9:24', freq='1T')
df1 = pd.DataFrame(index=dr, data=range(len(dr)), columns=['A'])

#two
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'dates':dr,
                    'values':np.random.rand(len(dr)),
                    'cat':np.random.choice(['a','b'],len(dr))})
```

---

<sub>1. And for the record, I reckon the onus should be on posters to post their data in a more copy-able format, else not get answered.  For time series information, rather than pasting the string representation of the DataFrame I always try to post **constructing code** (using `pd.date_range()` or w/e).  And I imagine using something like `df.to_dict()` would be better if there are specific (irregular interval) dates that need to be copied for the example.</sub>

Comment: Usually I go with `pd.read_clipboard(sep=\s\s+)`.

Comment: @HenryYik this is good, I didn't know that `sep` would fix the first example.  But still fails for the second?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually copy the entire string and then parse it. It's not perfect and you usually have to edit both the string and the dataframe to make it usable. Here is one example. This solution was already provided in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53692642/4383754). I've only added the bit about parsing date/time.

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
from dateutil.parser import parse

# I added two more column names `date` and `time`.
# An advantage of having the string in your python code is that
# you can edit it in your text editor/jupyter notebook quickly and directly.
s = """date time A
2020-01-01 09:20:00  0
2020-01-01 09:21:00  1
2020-01-01 09:22:00  2
2020-01-01 09:23:00  3
2020-01-01 09:24:00  4"""

# Parse using whitespace separator. This will still not be perfect as we can
# see below.
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), sep="\s+", index_col=False)
df
#          date      time  A
# 0  2020-01-01  09:20:00  0
# 1  2020-01-01  09:21:00  1
# 2  2020-01-01  09:22:00  2
# 3  2020-01-01  09:23:00  3
# 4  2020-01-01  09:24:00  4

# Combine date and time column together and drop the individual columns.
df['datetime'] = df['date'] + " " + df['time']
df = df.drop(['date', 'time'], axis=1)

# Use a somewhat universal parser in dateutil.parser.parse to parse the
# dates into proper dateime object.
df['datetime'] = df['datetime'].apply(parse)
df
#    A            datetime
# 0  0 2020-01-01 09:20:00
# 1  1 2020-01-01 09:21:00
# 2  2 2020-01-01 09:22:00
# 3  3 2020-01-01 09:23:00
# 4  4 2020-01-01 09:24:00

df.index
# RangeIndex(start=0, stop=5, step=1)

df.dtypes
# A                    int64
# datetime    datetime64[ns]
# dtype: object

df.columns
# Index(['A', 'datetime'], dtype='object')
```

One method to provide formatted and parseable dataframe on StackOverflow is by outputting a csv-formatted string.

```py
# Continued from above
print(df.to_csv(index=False))
# A,datetime
# 0,2020-01-01 09:20:00
# 1,2020-01-01 09:21:00
# 2,2020-01-01 09:22:00
# 3,2020-01-01 09:23:00
# 4,2020-01-01 09:24:00

# We can indeed parse nicely from the csv-formatted string 
s_redux = df.to_csv(index=False)
pd.read_csv(StringIO(s_redux))
#    A             datetime
# 0  0  2020-01-01 09:20:00
# 1  1  2020-01-01 09:21:00
# 2  2  2020-01-01 09:22:00
# 3  3  2020-01-01 09:23:00
# 4  4  2020-01-01 09:24:00
```

Here is one attempt at parsing the second example dataframe. As before, we do need to make some "edits" to the dataframe to make it usable.

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
from dateutil.parser import parse

s="""                dates    values cat
0 2020-01-01 09:20:00  0.758513   a
1 2020-01-01 09:21:00  0.337325   b
2 2020-01-01 09:22:00  0.618372   b
3 2020-01-01 09:23:00  0.878714   b
4 2020-01-01 09:24:00  0.311069   b"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), sep="\s+").reset_index()
df
#    level_0     level_1     dates    values cat
# 0        0  2020-01-01  09:20:00  0.758513   a
# 1        1  2020-01-01  09:21:00  0.337325   b
# 2        2  2020-01-01  09:22:00  0.618372   b
# 3        3  2020-01-01  09:23:00  0.878714   b
# 4        4  2020-01-01  09:24:00  0.311069   b

df['dates'] = df['level_1'] + " " + df['dates']
df = df.drop(['level_0', 'level_1'], axis=1)
df['dates'] = df['dates'].apply(parse)

df
#                 dates    values cat
# 0 2020-01-01 09:20:00  0.758513   a
# 1 2020-01-01 09:21:00  0.337325   b
# 2 2020-01-01 09:22:00  0.618372   b
# 3 2020-01-01 09:23:00  0.878714   b
# 4 2020-01-01 09:24:00  0.311069   b

df.dtypes
# dates     datetime64[ns]
# values           float64
# cat               object
# dtype: object
```

Comment: Consider `pandas.to_datetime` instead of loop version of `apply` + `parse`.

Comment: You're right `pd.to_datetime` should be faster, especially if there are repeated datetime strings. It can also parse datetimes from multiple columns, which should be quite useful. I happen to like `dateutil.parser.parse` when performance is not an issue (such as for StackOverflow dataframes) because I've been using it for a long time for parsing datetimes in general.

Answer (score 1):

What I normally do for Pandas SO questions is simply quote the date and time values (after copy-paste). If rows are numerous, I will use a text editor to do a Find/Replace to add quotes usually before year pattern (`20XX`) and after day pattern (`-01`). From there, using `StringIO`, specify `parse_dates` and as needed the `index_col` argument in [**`read.csv`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) (or `read.table`)

**Datetime as Index**

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

txt = '''             A
"2020-01-01 09:20:00" 0
"2020-01-01 09:21:00" 1
"2020-01-01 09:22:00" 2
"2020-01-01 09:23:00" 3
"2020-01-01 09:24:00" 4'''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), sep="\s+", parse_dates=True)

df.index    
# DatetimeIndex(['2020-01-01 09:20:00', '2020-01-01 09:21:00',
#                '2020-01-01 09:22:00', '2020-01-01 09:23:00',
#                '2020-01-01 09:24:00'],
#               dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

**Datetime as column**

```
txt = '''         dates    value  cat
0 "2020-01-01 09:20:00"  0.758513   a
1 "2020-01-01 09:21:00"  0.337325   b
2 "2020-01-01 09:22:00"  0.618372   b
3 "2020-01-01 09:23:00"  0.878714   b
4 "2020-01-01 09:24:00"  0.311069   b'''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), sep="\s+", index_col=[0], parse_dates=["dates"])

df.dtypes
# dates     datetime64[ns]
# values           float64
# cat               object
# dtype: object
```