# How can I align a merged dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, cross-join

I have two datasets. One with supplies, other with sales. They have different dates and time.

Suppplies

```
         Year      Month   Day  Hour       Item
    0    2023       05     17    10         8 
    1    2023       06     01    12         8 
    2    2023       06     10    16         3
    3    2023       06     17    10         8 
    4    2023       07     01    10         8 
    5    2023       08     17    10         8
```

Sales

```
         Year      Month   Day  Hour       Sale
    0    2023       05     17    16         3 
    1    2023       05     18    12         3 
    2    2023       05     24    16         3 
    3    2023       05     27    10         1 
    4    2023       06     02    10         2 
    5    2023       06     03    10         3
```

I need both information so i merged them

```
         Year      Month   Day  Hour       Item    Year      Month   Day  Hour       Item  
    0    2023       05     17    10         8      2023       05     17    16         3
    1    2023       06     01    12         8      2023       05     18    12         3
    2    2023       06     10    16         3      2023       05     24    16         3
    3    2023       06     17    10         8      2023       05     27    10         1
    4    2023       07     01    10         8      2023       06     02    10         2
    5    2023       08     17    10         8      2023       06     03    10    3
```

I want that if there was no delivery on that day, then the date on the right is duplicated and the quantity is 0. Until a new delivery

I desire to get

```
         Year      Month   Day  Hour       Item    Year      Month   Day  Hour       Item  
    0    2023       05     17    10         8      2023       05     17    16         3
    1    2023      NaN    NaN    NaN        0      2023       05     18    12         3
    2    2023       NaN    NaN    NaN       0      2023       05     20    16         3
    3    2023      NaN    NaN    NaN        0      2023       05     27    10         1
    4    2023       06     01    12         8      2023       06     02    10         2
    5    2023      NaN    NaN    NaN        0      2023       06     03    10         3
```

I would like to get this result, if the date value on the left is less than the date value on the right, and if the value in the column is 0 then it will be replaced by nan.

Comment: How do you know if a delivery has been made on a given day?

Comment: 3rd row in desired output is `2023-05-20`? 5th row `2023-06-01`?

Comment: Delivery day if "Item" not equal zero

Comment: @PandaKim I would like the year month and day to be copied from the sales column until the delivery day (when the item is not zero).

Comment: In the expected output, why are there two different dates in row with index 4, i.e. `2023-06-01` vs `2023-06-02`? Would you mind explaining this?

Comment: @SimonDavid, I changed the wording of the desired result

Comment: @Olsen_I It seems that row with index 5 of the expected output still does not match the data that was provided for supplies and sales - would you mind revising or explaining to me how that data point comes about?

Comment: Sure. @SimonDavid The supplies date is almost always different from the sales date. I would like to create a general dataframe for analysis. The idea came to my mind that maybe I could combine them but fill in the NAN rows when the sale date is later than the supply date

Comment: @Olsen_I I understand what you want to do. My question is regarding that specific data point. In order for writing you the code which does what you want, inputs and expected output need to make 100% sense. Alas, row with index 5 doesn't - the left part of your expected outcome represents the `supplies` table, but the record ` 5    2023       06     03    10  ...` does not exist in the original `supplies` table but is in the `sales` table, which is why I asked you if you can explain to me the "business logic" that lead to the expected outcome, or correct any errors in the table if there are.

Comment: @SimonDavid I am apologize for that misunderstanding. I was my misclick. Thank you for comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways how the two datasets can be combined in the desired way:

1. **Conditional, `SQL`-like join on the supplies and sales dates.** In particular, a particular sales record will be joined with the current supply record when the sales date is equal to/after the date of the current supply record, where the date of the sales record must not be greater than the date of the subsequent supply record.
2. **Cartesian product of both tables with subsequent filter.** We cross-join all rows of both tables and subsequently filter the data as mentioned in 1.

To the best of my knowledge, conditional joins (as they exist in `SQL`) cannot be done in `pandas` [see this SO post here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30630905/8718701)

Below you can find the code showing how both approaches can be done, where the first approach also requires the `sqlite3` module. I personally would recommend you the first approach as performing a cross join can be computationally very expensive.

**Code for first approach:**

```
# loading data using solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/53692642/8718701
from io import StringIO

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3

d = '''
         Year      Month   Day  Hour       Item
    0    2023       05     17    10         8
    1    2023       06     01    12         8
    2    2023       06     10    16         3
    3    2023       06     17    10         8
    4    2023       07     01    10         8
    5    2023       08     17    10         8
'''

supplies_df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(d), sep='\s+')

d = '''
         Year      Month   Day  Hour       Sale
    0    2023       05     17    16         3
    1    2023       05     18    12         3
    2    2023       05     24    16         3
    3    2023       05     27    10         1
    4    2023       06     02    10         2
    5    2023       06     03    10         3
'''

sales_df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(d), sep='\s+')

# first approach based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/42796283/8718701

supplies_df['supply_datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(
    supplies_df[['Year', 'Month', 'Day', 'Hour']]
)
supplies_df['next_supply_datetime'] = supplies_df['supply_datetime'].shift(-1)

sales_df['sale_datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(
    sales_df[['Year', 'Month', 'Day', 'Hour']]
)

#Make the db in memory
conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
#write the tables
supplies_df.to_sql('supplies', conn, index=False)
sales_df.to_sql('sales', conn, index=False)

# query joining tables on conditional join:
# join a sales record only if its datetime is equal to/greater than the datetime
# of the current supply record as well as smaller than the datetime of the
# subsequent supply record
qry = '''
    SELECT 
        A.supply_datetime,
        A.Year AS supply_year,
        A.Month AS supply_month,
        A.Day AS supply_day,
        A.Hour AS supply_hour,
        A.Item,
        B.sale_datetime,
        B.Year AS sale_year,
        B.Month AS sale_month,
        B.Day AS sale_day,
        B.Hour AS sale_hour,
        B.Sale
    FROM supplies AS A
    JOIN sales AS B
    ON A.supply_datetime <= B.sale_datetime
        AND A.next_supply_datetime > B.sale_datetime
    '''
df = pd.read_sql_query(qry, conn)

# remove duplicated info
record_is_dupe = df.duplicated('supply_datetime')
cols_to_remove = [
    'supply_datetime', 'supply_year',
    'supply_month', 'supply_day', 'supply_hour'
]
df.loc[record_is_dupe, cols_to_remove] = np.NaN
df.loc[record_is_dupe, ['Item']] = 0

# remove datetime columns
df.drop(columns=['supply_datetime', 'sale_datetime'], inplace=True)

# matches expected output
print(df.to_markdown(index=False))

# |   supply_year |   supply_month |   supply_day |   supply_hour |   Item |   sale_year |   sale_month |   sale_day |   sale_hour |   Sale |
# |--------------:|---------------:|-------------:|--------------:|-------:|------------:|-------------:|-----------:|------------:|-------:|
# |          2023 |              5 |           17 |            10 |      8 |        2023 |            5 |         17 |          16 |      3 |
# |           nan |            nan |          nan |           nan |      0 |        2023 |            5 |         18 |          12 |      3 |
# |           nan |            nan |          nan |           nan |      0 |        2023 |            5 |         24 |          16 |      3 |
# |           nan |            nan |          nan |           nan |      0 |        2023 |            5 |         27 |          10 |      1 |
# |          2023 |              6 |            1 |            12 |      8 |        2023 |            6 |          2 |          10 |      2 |
# |           nan |            nan |          nan |           nan |      0 |        2023 |            6 |          3 |          10 |      3 |
```

**Code for second approach:**

```
# loading data using solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/53692642/8718701
from io import StringIO

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

d = '''
         Year      Month   Day  Hour       Item
    0    2023       05     17    10         8
    1    2023       06     01    12         8
    2    2023       06     10    16         3
    3    2023       06     17    10         8
    4    2023       07     01    10         8
    5    2023       08     17    10         8
'''

supplies_df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(d), sep='\s+')

d = '''
         Year      Month   Day  Hour       Sale
    0    2023       05     17    16         3
    1    2023       05     18    12         3
    2    2023       05     24    16         3
    3    2023       05     27    10         1
    4    2023       06     02    10         2
    5    2023       06     03    10         3
'''

sales_df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(d), sep='\s+')

# second approach based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/53699198/8718701

supplies_df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(
    supplies_df[['Year', 'Month', 'Day', 'Hour']]
)
supplies_df['datetime_shift'] = supplies_df['datetime'].shift(-1)
supplies_df.columns = ['supply_' + col.lower() for col in supplies_df.columns]

# renaming columns as duplicate names cause problems
sales_df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(
    sales_df[['Year', 'Month', 'Day', 'Hour']]
)
sales_df.columns = ['sale_' + col.lower() for col in sales_df.columns]

# Cartesian product
df = pd.merge(left=supplies_df, right=sales_df, how='cross')

# Filtering rows based on condition
winnowing_condition = (
    ((df['supply_datetime'] <= df['sale_datetime'])
    & (df['supply_datetime_shift'] > df['sale_datetime']))
)
df = df.loc[winnowing_condition, :]

# remove duplicated info
record_is_dupe = df.duplicated('supply_datetime')
cols_to_remove = [
    'supply_datetime', 'supply_year',
    'supply_month', 'supply_day', 'supply_hour'
]
df.loc[record_is_dupe, cols_to_remove] = np.NaN
df.loc[record_is_dupe, ['supply_item']] = 0

# remove datetime columns
cols_to_drop = ['supply_datetime', 'sale_datetime', 'supply_datetime_shift']
df.drop(columns=cols_to_drop, inplace=True)
df.rename(columns={'supply_item': 'Item', 'sale_sale': 'Sale'}, inplace=True)

# matches expected output
print(df.to_markdown(index=False))


# |   supply_year |   supply_month |   supply_day |   supply_hour |   Item |   sale_year |   sale_month |   sale_day |   sale_hour |   Sale |
# |--------------:|---------------:|-------------:|--------------:|-------:|------------:|-------------:|-----------:|------------:|-------:|
# |          2023 |              5 |           17 |            10 |      8 |        2023 |            5 |         17 |          16 |      3 |
# |           nan |            nan |          nan |           nan |      0 |        2023 |            5 |         18 |          12 |      3 |
# |           nan |            nan |          nan |           nan |      0 |        2023 |            5 |         24 |          16 |      3 |
# |           nan |            nan |          nan |           nan |      0 |        2023 |            5 |         27 |          10 |      1 |
# |          2023 |              6 |            1 |            12 |      8 |        2023 |            6 |          2 |          10 |      2 |
# |           nan |            nan |          nan |           nan |      0 |        2023 |            6 |          3 |          10 |      3 |
```