# How to perform 'OR' between muliple columns in python dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

my df:

```
No  A   B   C  D
1   1   1   0  1
2   1   1   1  0
3   1   0   1  1
4   1   1   1  1
```

I would like to perform A or B or C or D and write the result in a column.

```
No  A   B   C  D Result
1   1   1   0  1 1
2   1   1   1  0 1
3   1   0   1  1 1
4   1   1   1  1 1
...
```

so the idea is, the result is '1' even if there is one '1' present either in A,B,C or D.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Logical OR on a subset of columns in a DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31606137/logical-or-on-a-subset-of-columns-in-a-dataframe)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One idea is use [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for test at least one `1` per rows or use `max` per rows:

```
#if No is column
df['Result'] = df.iloc[:, 1:].any(axis=1).astype(int)
#if No is index
#df['Result'] = df.any(axis=1).astype(int)
```

If some another columns:

```
df['Result'] = df[['A','B','C','D']].any(axis=1).astype(int)
```

Or:

```
df['Result'] = df[['A','B','C','D']].max(axis=1)
```

---

---

```
print (df)

   No  A  B  C  D  Result
0   1  1  1  0  1       1
1   2  1  1  1  0       1
2   3  1  0  1  1       1
3   4  1  1  1  1       1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
df['Result'] = df.drop('No', axis=1).max(1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   No  A  B  C  D  Result
0   1  1  1  0  1       1
1   2  1  1  1  0       1
2   3  1  0  1  1       1
3   4  1  1  1  1       1
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to the list of funny ways:

```
df_a['Result'] = df_a.eval('A + B + C').astype(bool)
```

The advantage is that eval doesn't make intermediate tables in the memory.
If you need explicit *int* instead of *bool*, you can cast it, of course:

```
df_a['Result'] = df_a.eval('A + B + C').astype(bool).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 1):

Strangely, no one mentioned the use of simple `|` operator.

Answer to your question

```
df['Result'] = df['A'] | df['B'] | df['C'] | df['D']
```

Similarly, if you want to perform other operations like `AND`

```
df['Result'] = df['A'] & df['B'] & df['C'] & df['D']
```